# Blurring Background (Acrylic Effect) in GLFW/OpenGL Window

Tags: c++, windows, opengl, glfw

How do I make the window background display a blurred version all windows below it (similar to the [Windows Acrylic Effect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/style/acrylic)).

1. The [DWM BlurBehind](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dwmapi/nf-dwmapi-dwmenableblurbehindwindow) is not working and seems to be deprecated.
2. I cant find any official documentation for SetWindowCompositionAttribute nor any c++ version of the same

Is there any way to use SetWindowCompositionAttribute with a GLFW window ? Or alternatively Render the whole window (effectively screen capture) to a frame buffer and then manually apply the blur? What is the viability of such a method for a lightweight application?

Answer (score 1):

GLFW itself does not support such a feature, however, there is an open [issue](https://github.com/glfw/glfw/issues/1823) for it.

You can write platform specific code with GLFW. GLFW provides [functions to retrieve the underlying platform specific constructs](https://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__native.html).

Something like this might work (version 3.4):

```c
if (glfwGetPlatform() == GLFW_PLATFORM_WIN32) {
    HWND nativeWindow = glfwGetWin32Window(window);

    const HRESULT returnCode = DwmSetWindowAttribute(
        nativeWindow,
        ...,
        ...,
        ...
    );
}
```

Comment: Oh, funny. I just noticed your profile picture in that Github issue thread.